# How to remove the last element in each list in a list

Tags: python, list

I've got a list like:

```
alist = [[a,b,(1,2)], [a,b,(1,2)], [a,b,(1,2)]]
```

I want to remove the last element from all the elements in a list. So the result will be:

```
alist = [[a,b], [a,b], [a,b]]
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: What tutorial are you using to learn Python?

Comment: what is this nonsensical addition? what do you mean it doesn't work? why are you posting a code from an answer?

Comment: "Your script works in python shell, but does not work in my program, don't know why is that"?  What does this mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use list comprehension to create a new list that removes the last element.

```
>>> alist = [[1,2,(3,4)],[5,6,(7,8)],[9,10,(11,12)]]
>>> [x[:-1] for x in alist]       # <-------------
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10]]
```

However, if you want efficiency you could modify the list in-place:

```
>>> alist = [[1,2,(3,4)],[5,6,(7,8)],[9,10,(11,12)]]
>>> for x in alist: del x[-1]       # <-------------
... 
>>> alist
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10]]
```

Comment: Beat me by 15 seconds.  I shouldn't have wasted time wondering why the person isn't using a good Python tutorial.

Comment: I felt the urge to remove some clutter.  Your first answer was approximately perfect.  The detailed example might be more helpful, but, I think it's clearer with two fewer lines of distraction from that essential, crystal clear line of code.

Comment: "if you want efficiency"?  How is this more efficient?  Do you have some numbers to support this claim?

Comment: @S.Lott: Sure http://www.ideone.com/4JajX. In fact, it is quite clear that the 1st version is slower because the whole list is copied.

Answer (score -2):

This is basic Python stuff. You should be able to do it after reading the Python tutorial

```
>>> alist = [[1,2,(3,4)],[5,6,(7,8)],[9,10,(11,12)]]
>>> for li in alist:
...     print li[0:2]
...
[1, 2]
[5, 6]
[9, 10]
>>>
```

Later on, you can go to intermediate stuff like list comprehension etc